# ionic3 camera move the image from cache and getting the base64 data

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

i am new to Ionic and i am trying to send an image to API which requires base64 encoding the encoding is not working when i take the picture from Ionic camera plugin as it gives me the cache path however i am able to retrieve the image using file reader my code below

HTML FIle

```
<button ion-button round (click)="takePicture()">Take a Picture</button>
 Uploaded Picture:
 <img [src]=[base64Image] *ngIf="base64Image" />
```

TS File

```
takePicture(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(200);
    let options = {
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
      targetWidth: 300,
      targetHeight: 300,
      quality: 100,
      allowEdit: false,
      correctOrientation: false,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };
    this.camera.getPicture(options)
    .then((imageData)=>{
      console.log(imageData);
      this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageData;
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

When i try the same using file reader it works

```
onFileChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
        this.base64 = (<FileReader>event.target).result;

        console.log(event.target);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

HTML File

```
 <input type="file" id="lic" name="lic" (change)="onFileChange($event)" capture="camera" accept="image/*"/>
          <button ion-button round (click)="licensify()">Upload</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Camera.DestinationType](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameradestinationtype--enum) : DATA_URL, this will return a ' base64 encoded string' in the getPicture Promise.

So your ts file should look like this

```
  takePicture(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(200);
    let options = {
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      targetWidth: 300,
      targetHeight: 300,
      quality: 100,
      allowEdit: false,
      correctOrientation: false,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };
    this.camera.getPicture(options)
    .then((imageData)=>{
      console.log(imageData);
      //base64 encoded string

      this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageData;
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```